# How can I surround an image with two <div>s on one line?

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`s surrounding an `image` in same row, but when I add the image the right `<div>` drops below.

I've tried `float`, `display:inline-block` and even styling the `HTML`tags, but it didn't help.

Please help me out.
Here's my `code`:

```
  <title>Hair by Michelle</title>
<body>
<div class="all">
    <div class="navbar">

        <img class="pic1" src="https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/598668_4520542180477_68371292_n.jpg?oh=024b6348716dcf01475a40d0576671e7&oe=5640E0C7" alt="Photo of Michelle>

        <h1>Hair By Michelle</h1>

        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="about"><a href="#">about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="availability"><a href="http://hairbymichelle.simplybook.me/sheduler/manage/">appointments</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hours">
            <h1>Hours</h1>

        <p>Tuesday: 12pm-7pm</p>
        </br>
        <p>Wednesday: 12pm-7pm</p>
        </br>
        <p>Thursday: 10am-7pm</p>
        </br>
        <p>Every other Saturday: 10am-7pm</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>

            <h4>Women's Haircut $32</h4>

        </br>
            <h4>Men's Haircut $22</h4>

        </br>
            <h4>Full head color $50</h4>

        </br>
            <h4>Full highlights $70</h4>

        </br>
            <h4>Color toning $15</h4>

        </br>
            <h4>Facial waxing $12</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

Ignore the result area, just paste it in an editor.

Comment: A `JSFiddle` would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want elements to line up in the same line should add:

```
float:left;
position:relative;
```

for the HTML I would recommend each image in a div:

```css
.imgrow {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="imgrow"><img class="imgrow" src="https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/598668_4520542180477_68371292_n.jpg?oh=024b6348716dcf01475a40d0576671e7&oe=5640E0C7"></div>
<div class="imgrow"><img class="imgrow" src="https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/598668_4520542180477_68371292_n.jpg?oh=024b6348716dcf01475a40d0576671e7&oe=5640E0C7"></div>
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

I see just one image in your code...
If you need the text to be displayed next to the image, try this-

```
<div class="navbar">
<div style="float:left;">
        <img class="pic1" src="https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/598668_4520542180477_68371292_n.jpg?oh=024b6348716dcf01475a40d0576671e7&oe=5640E0C7" alt="Photo of Michelle">
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
        <h1>Hair By Michelle</h1>

        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="availability"><a href="http://hairbymichelle.simplybook.me/sheduler/manage/">appointments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```